# RPI cluster - Quality vs Quantity

Tags: cluster

If I have a fixed amount of money to invest in making a cluster, let's say 165$, I could buy 4 'rpi 4's(1GB ram) or 3 'rpi 4's(4GB ram), or 33 rpi zeros.

Thinking about the cost of the boards only, what would have the best performance/money ratio?

We can also think about mixing the boards; would a rpi 4(4GB ram) as master and rpi zeros as slaves be better than just using one type of board, etc

I think one of the important factors other than cpu/ram would be the availability of gigabit ethernet. Since the zero doesn't have one, it might have a big impact on the performance.

Let's say raspberry pi zero got updated - buyers now have the choice of adding Gigabit Ethernet at +3$.(8$ total)

So, again, what choice of boards would have the best performance/money ratio?

Comment: You might want to take the [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) - as by referring to a product that is NOT designed by the Raspberry Pi Foundation you are crossing the line into being ***off-topic*** (and thus rendering the question a candidate for closure).  It would be best to remove that aspect of the question. Even then it might not be possible to come up with a response that is unequivocally the *right* one just by considering *official* RPis - and it would also need to consider the cost of the support networking hardware needed - wireless-linked RPi3Bs might be best combo!

Comment: I want to know 
a) if it is better to have a high spec rpi as master, 
b) if it is better to have many low spec slaves opposed to having few high spec slaves, 
c) how important the connection between the RPIs are in relative to the other specs
;
but in order to ask c), I have to bring in another board, since there is only 1 RPI equipped with GbE. I edited so that this question would be more on topic anyway